# Multiple tables with same columns or one table with an additional FK column

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am working on a project where I have sensors that will store some data (let's say for health monitoring) into a Database, for retrieval later via an API. I will have the same set of sensors (about 10 different sensors) in multiple locations. That data will be stored in the DB every five minutes. So every 5 minutes I will have a new row for each set of sensors.

Since I will have multiple locations, and this needs to be scalable, I don't know if I should have one table for each location or if I should have one huge table with an extra column to identify which location that row belongs to.

For example:

- If I have 10 monitoring stations, should I have 10 tables with same columns and different names
  (station1, station2, station3, station4...),
  that receives 1 row each every 5 minutes ?
- Or should I have a single table with an additional column specifying the location of the monitoring station
  (row: timeStamp, bloodSugar, heartBeat, ..., stationName),
  that receives 10 rows every 5 minutes ?

Comment: Option 1 is definitely wrong. Option 2 is better, but may need some tweaking. Probably you want two tables - one which stores general information common to all readings, and another which stores the station and monitor.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I do have another table that contains information on each of the stations, like the address, latitude, longitude, technical aspects, etc. My concern is with this one big table with several rows. Thinking of scalability, if I get to 100 locations, I would have more than 20k new rows in one table per day. Is that something ok? I am still a noobie with databases.

Comment: I'm thinking of scalability. If you collected data every day for 100 years that would be about a billion rows. So, nothing to worry about - although you might like to read about partitioning.

Comment: Oh, that is great! That really helps! So far I've only done school projects with less than hundreds of rows, so I didn't know how many rows were too many rows. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So every 5 minutes I will have a new row for each set of sensors in my DB.

Well, it would be very silly to INSERT a new row just because it came down the line from the Sensor controller.  That would be **un**scalable, you will fill the database with data that does not changes: duplicates.

- You need to INSERT a new row only when *one* of the data values in the row has changed since the previous row for the (Station, TimeStamp).

> Since I will have multiple locations, and this needs to be scalable, I don't know if I should have one table for each location .

That has nothing to do with scalability.

That is simply a gross Normalisation error.

> or if I should have one huge table with an extra column to identify which location that row belongs to

That is Normalised.

It is not an "extra" column, it is an ordinary, Identifying column.

The table is not "huge" or "massive".  The sum total rows in the database are the same for either option.  The index will handle the queries just fine.

- Commercial RDBMSs handle millions of rows per second.  MySQL is not commercial, does not even comply with the SQL requirement (the use of the term SQL is misleading), and it does not have a Server Architecture.  Therefore do not expect commercial performance from it.  However, it should be able to comfortably manage INSERTing 0-to-10 rows every 5 mins.

> For example: If I have 10 monitoring stations, should I have 10 tables with same columns and different names (station1, station2, station3, station4...)?

As explained above, definitely not.

> Or should I have a <strike>massive</strike> table that will get [zero to] 10 new rows every 5 minutes with an <strike>extra</strike> column specifying the <strike>location of the</strike> monitoring station? (row: timeStamp, bloodSugar, heartBeat, ..., stationName)

As explained above, yes.

### Relational Data Model

[image: AugustoTA]

The Fact of a Station (which has certain attributes), and the Fact of a Reading (which has certain attributes), are two separate things.

#### Note • Notation

- All my data models are rendered in [IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/), the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My [IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) is essential reading for beginners